# python dictionaries. Two strings as key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm new to python and trying to figure out how to take 3 strings separated by space as input and then the first two will be the key of the desired dictionary and the 3rd string would be the key:

example:

```
 John Smith 1234
 Mike Tyson 5678
```

dictonary should be like this:

```
{'John Smith': '1234', 'Mike Tyson': '5678'}
```

if it was just two strings that's pretty straightforward and i get the right answer:

```
   count=int(input())
   d=dict(input().split() for x in range(count))
   print(d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# generator to yield input until an empty string is entered
def get_input():
    s = input()
    while s:
        yield s
        s = input()

# get input from the generator, split at the last " " and make a dict from it
d = dict(line.rsplit(maxsplit=1) for line in get_input())
```

A function to chose the number of loops at the beginning:

```
def get_input():
    count = int(input("how many entries: "))
    for _ in range(count):
        yield input()
```

Comment: very close to what I am looking for but instead of empty string it should be looped based on an integer as the first input from user: 
ex input:
2
john smith 123
mike tyson 456

output:{'John Smith': '1234', 'Mike Tyson': '5678'}

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`rsplit`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rsplit.html) with `maxsplit=1`; that way, you only split once from the right:

```
lst = ['John Smith 1234', 'Mike Tyson 5678']
d = {}
for string in lst:
    s = string.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
    d[s[0]] = s[1]
```

Output:

```
{'John Smith': '1234', 'Mike Tyson': '5678'}
```

Comment: Here you are already putting the strings in a list but in real scenario  you need to  get them as input from user and then convert to list?

Comment: no ; each on separate line:
first line: John Smith 1234
second line Mike Tyson 5678

Comment: not exactly... code goes through a loop and based on the range it will take a new input from user in each line.. so if n is=2 then first input: John Smith 1234 hit enter and next line second input:Mike Tyson 5678

Comment: @moin1010 and you store the user input how? presumably in a list, right?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: @moin1010 then the code will work as it's written

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string inputs is fixed to be = 3 and that you are going to receive the strings into a list:

```
from functools import reduce

S = ["John Smith 1234", "Mike Tyson 5678"]

reduce(lambda x,y: dict(x, **y), [dict([[" ".join(s.split()[:2]),s.split()[-1]]]) for s in S])

>> {'John Smith': '1234', 'Mike Tyson': '5678'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rsplit last item.

```py
count = int(input("How many times data you want to enter: "))
data_list = [input("Please enter the {} data: ".format(x + 1)) for x in range(count)]

output_dict = dict(item.rsplit(' ', 1) for item in data_list)
print("Output:\n", output_dict)
>>
```

Output:

```
How many times data you want to enter: 2
Please enter the 1 data: John Smith 1234
Please enter the 2 data: Mike Tyson 5678
Output:
 {'John Smith': '1234', 'Mike Tyson': '5678'}
```

Answer (score -1):

could use `str.rpartition()`. This returns a tuple of the first two strings, the space, and the final string. (Python 3.10)

```
s = input()
key, space, final = s.rpartition(' ')
d = {key:final}
```